# c# Is passing a CancellationToken okay?

Tags: c#, wpf

Would it be okay to run a method like this in my Tasks when updating my WPF UI?

```
   public static void InvokeOnUiThread(Action action, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (Application.Current == null) return;
        if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
        }
    }
```

I'd also like to pass a null but havent figured out how to make CancellationToken nullable.

Comment: `CancellationToken.None` is the "null" equivalent

Comment: It is not okay.  The odds that it got cancelled a nanosecond after you called the method are zero.

Comment: I thought it was a check to see if cancel was already requested so it wont go to the UI.  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making it an optional parameter with a default value

```
static void InvokeOnUiThread(Action action, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken)) {
    //...
}
```

That way the method can be called with just the action

Comment: Any idea what Hans is talking about,  Isn't the token a ref?